# Warning: Unimplemented Selector localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.2

I'm getting the subject warning on the following line:

```
   NSSortDescriptor * sort = [ [NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                 ascending:YES
                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:) ];
```

And I didn't always get that warning.  That is, the warning just started to appear recently, possibly due to a change in compilation settings.  I don't see a typo, here.  This looks (to me) just like code I've seen in many examples.  I'm not seeing a run time exception.  But I don't like warnings.  Anyone seen this?  Any idea what's triggering it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you turn on `-Wselector`? (Also called "Multiple Definition Types for Selector.") This warning is incompatible with Foundation and you should not turn it on. It exists because it does make sense in "pure" Objective-C. Just not in any Objective-C you'd ever be likely to write (i.e. anything that uses Cocoa).

The warning you want is `-Wundeclared-selector`, also called "Undeclared Selector."

It's somewhat dated, but I've compiled a complete list of GCC warnings and whether to turn them on or off in my [Shared.xcconfig](https://github.com/rnapier/cocoaphony/blob/master/Project%20Templates/iPhoneOS/Window-Based%20Application/XCConfig/Shared.xcconfig) file. There is also a [very helpful bestiary compiled by Jean-David Gadina](http://www.noxeos.com/2011/02/04/xcode-build-settings/) that is a bit more up-to-date.

Comment: Hi @Rob Napier, I just updated to xcode 5 and I am getting the warning "Selector not found", As you suggested I checked the option "Multiple Definition Types for Selector", and its already set to NO. But still I get the warning. So what to do.

Comment: That's a different warning than this question is about. If you're getting that warning after upgrading, that suggests that you're using a method that has been removed. You should open a new question with details of what method you're using, what SDK you're using, and the exact warning (though I would start by just verifying that the method actually exists).